# Why my site isn't getting approved by AdSense?

Tags: adsense

I have a website under construction in Blogger, but my Adsense account is not approved as I received the email that my site is not meeting the Google guidelines.
Message :
valuable inventory: under construction

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not programming related. It might be on topic for the Webmasters Stack Exchange

Comment: You said the site was under construct, the message says that its rejected because its under construction. So …

Answer (score -1):

In order to enable AdSense in your blog and this be approved by Google, your site have to include content and important information. Your site is checked by Google for this information and decide about your site is suitable to host Google ads...If your site is under construction, this is not possible